# Modal element is not hiding [React & React - Bootstrap]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap

I've created modal with React Bootstrap. Despite the fact, that I'm using onHide function, nothing happens. Here's my modal:

```
        <React.Fragment>
            <Modal
                {...this.props}
                bsSize="large"
                aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-lg"
                show={this.state.showModal}
                onHide={this.handleHide}
             >
            <Modal.Body>
               ...
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
               <Button id = "closeModal" variant="danger" onClick= 
               {this.handleHide.bind(this)}>
                            Save and close
               </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </React.Fragment>
```

I'm passing "show" from other component, when click occurs on some element. onClick on that element is specified to: "showModal: true". Then I'm passing showModal to other component that is rendering different elements according to option choosed:

```
{this.state.addingState && (
    <MyForm
        {...this.state.item}
        show={this.state.showModal}
        ...
    />
)}
```

At last in MyForm component I have function that passes props to component with modal:

```
createModalComponent {
    ...
    let modalComponentProps= {
        ...
        show: this.props.show,
}
```

So, this is the way "show" is going. In my file with modal component I have function for handling hide:

```
handleHide() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
}
```

Now in this component showModal is initialize in state like so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        showModal: this.props.show
    };

    this.handleHide = this.handleHide.bind(this);
}
```

I've tried many things. Other state variables, without initializing showModal in state and many more. When clicking on the button or beyond the modal, modal is still visible and not hiding. I will be very grateful for your help and/or suggestions how to fix this.

So, the way showModal is going: parent component (where this.state.addingState is happening) -> MyForm component (where let modalComponentProps= { show: this.props.show, ... happens) -> actual modal component

[Code on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJBrXj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look on the `shouldComponentUpdate` method

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return !isEqual(this.props, nextProps);
}
```

You are checking only props but you are changing the state of the component. Fix the method or remove it and it will be working

Comment: It worked! But now I have other problem - I can't call back modal after hiding it

Comment: The reason why the modal behave like this is that the component is mounted and you are setting the initial state in constructor form the props. Then you determine if the modal is open or not based on its state and here is an issue. I prepared sandbox with an example of how you can solve something like that

https://codesandbox.io/s/1wr9641j77?fbclid=IwAR1cJltQDjNwJE9vFFPU6uX0EbM54MQbnDDlDsxKI61EXGncO_l93-iTMzo

Answer (score 3):

you have 2 possibilities: you can add the method to your parent and pass the method + the result of show like this (use same name of props and method for best practice, so you will be not confuse):

Parent

```
<Modal
    {...this.props}
    bsSize="large"
    aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-lg"
    show={this.state.showModal}
    handleHide={this.handleHide}
  >
```

Child

```
   <MyForm
        show={this.props.showModal}
        handleHide={this.props.handleHide}
    />
```

To use the modal from parent, you can call it like this in child: this.props.handleHide(true).

Or you let the child manage the state by itself, so you would place the method and state in child, not in parent (depending on the architecture).

It is not recommended to add the props in child state. 
Also, you could use es6 function to avoid binding like this:

```
handleHide = () => this.setState({ showModal: false });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So, if I understand you correctly (according to first option), I should create my handleHide method in parent, where showModal is also created? 
    handleHide() {
         this.setState({ showModal: false });
    }                                                                                                                                     and then pass this method as a prop, like I did with showModal? After that I can use this method in my Modal component by handleHide={this.handleHide} and in the button this.handleHide (without binding)?

Comment: I can't vote your reply up, bacause of my current reputation, but I will remember to do that later ;)

Comment: - Always use es6 functions in react, and never use binding again.
- Yes add handleHide() method to parent then when you pass it, your child can have access as props like this: this.props.handleHide.
- You can select my answer as the good one I think (no need to upvote), thank you^^

Comment: It didn't work or I did something wrong :( In component where click occurs and showModal: true I created method like this: handleHide = () => this.setState({ showModal: false }); Then I'm passing to next component method like this: onHide={this.state.handleHide}. Inside that component I'm passing method to actual modal component like this: let surveyFormItem = { onHide: this.props.onHide }. Also I'm initializing prop here like so: MyForm.propTypes { onHide: PropTypes.func } and MyForm.defaultProps { onHide: Function.prototype } .

Comment: Finally, in modal component <Modal
     {...this.props}
                                 ...
     show={this.state.showModal}
     onHide={this.props.onHide}
                                >    and button in this modal:                               
                                     <Button id = "closeModal" variant="danger" onClick={this.props.onHide}>
                       Save and exit
         </Button>

Comment: change this: onHide={this.state.handleHide} to this: onHide={this.handleHide}  

This is a component? : let surveyFormItem = { onHide: this.props.onHide } 

Generally we dont need to add defaultProps, you can delete the defaultProps and PropTypes (personally I dont think its very useful)

Comment: I changed it and still nothing :( Also, I've noticed error in the console: "React does not recognize the `showModal` prop on a DOM element." Same error appears to bsSize property in Modal. Yes, this is my component, which passes props to different forms - in my case I'm writing about case with modal component which contains form. I wrote different name for it in comment, sorry. I can't change it now, so modalComponentProps === surveyFormItem